# Adding '...' at the end of each second cell in my table

Tags: css

I would like to add 3 dots ("...") at the end of each second cell in my table because this is a column which expand with the window size (see screenshots below).

[image]

[image]

Here is my css:

```
table.list                 { table-layout:fixed; width: 100%; white-space: nowrap; }
table.list td              { border-bottom: 1px dotted #d9d9d9; height: 25px; padding-bottom: 2px; }
table.list th              { text-align:left; }
table.list td:nth-child(1), table.list th:nth-child(1) { width: 160px; }
table.list td:nth-child(2), table.list th:nth-child(2) { width: auto ; overflow:hidden; }
table.list td:nth-child(3), table.list th:nth-child(3) { width: 110px; padding-left: 20px; }
table.list td:nth-child(4), table.list th:nth-child(4) { width:  50px; padding-left: 20px; }
```

As you can see, the second cell is auto adjusting (hiding/showing text varying, depending on the window width).

I already try this one:

```
table.list td:nth-child(2):after { content: "..."; }
```

It doesn't work.

Any suggestions? Thanks.

**EDIT**

I update my question because I'm a step further with the help of Ofir Farchy See my demo here http://jsbin.com/ulofoq/23/edit#preview with Internet Explorer.

No problem with Chrome, only with Internet Explorer.

Let's try to resize the window and you'll see that I get '...' in front of the text in the first line of the table. That's ok. But for the second line these '...' are not showed !!??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried adding `text-overflow: ellipsis;` to the relevant cells' style?

You can read more about this [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/textoverflow.html) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/text-overflow).
I believe it is a CSS3 property (supported by almost all new browsers).

Comment: Great! I didn't know about ellipsis. I'm nearly good. But when I have a span with float:left in the <td> this ellipsis didn't work. Can you check? Here is the demo: http://jsbin.com/ulofoq/12/edit#source Simply resize the window, you 'll see the '...' for the first line of the table but not for the second!

Comment: I actually see both lines with the `...` (using chromium browser and firefox 7)

Comment: Mmm This is ok for Chrome but not for Internet Explorer! Any suggestion?

Comment: Ok, try adding a style for the span.  
something like:  
`table td span { white-space: nowrap; overflow:hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; }`

Comment: I did but nothing changed (updated my demo at jsbin.com/ulofoq/12/edit#source )

Comment: try replacing the style for `.access` to this: `{ max-width: 100%; float: left; white-space: nowrap; overflow:hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; }`.  
The `max-width` property should do the trick (if added to the other properties)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4907/discussion-between-ofir-farchy-and-bronzato)

Comment: Sorry but I had to leave now, I'll continue on this problem later. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2):

Your selector won't work as you're trying to add content in between `<td>`s. If you have another element within the `<td>` like `<span>`, you can select this with the after pseudo selector. This won't be great semantic markup, but it'll work.

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS works for me in firefox and IE.  See here jsbin.com/ulofoq/edit

Maybe you just using the wrong selector "table.list" ?

Comment: In fact, this solution is not what I was looking for: the '..' was added at the end of the text in the cell BUT when the text in the cell is partially hided, we won't see the '...' anymore. AND I would like to see the '...' at any time. See my screeshots above. Thanks.

Comment: please check the updated demo here: http://jsbin.com/ulofoq/12/edit#preview Simply resize the window, you 'll see the '...' for the first line of the table but not for the second!